# Do i need to register post type before inserting value under specific post type in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to record email address of user who are submitting their email address  from userend.

```
<?php
$my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Subscribed Email',
          'post_content'  => 'niroj@gmail.com',
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_author'   => 1,
          'post_type'     => 'subscription',
        );
$insertPost=wp_insert_post( $my_post );
?>
```

Here do i need to register subscription as a post type at first? Or it does not matter if i directly insert it with out registering post type?I do not need to show it on admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will insert custom post type entry into the database even if you do not register custom post type before, but without registering custom post type you will not have permalink structure associated with CPT and will not be able to access it via url and you will not have an admin interface.

Comment: Nick is correct. You can certainly insert it into the database but without registering the CPT, you won't have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a custom post type then you can add a custom meta box for email address as well and while inserting post data you can insert email to that meta box and that will make better sense in all cases, for creating custom post type visit this official WordPress page https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types